# Adding a small image or icon onto page in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular

I noticed when starting my first Angular project, the default Homepage is nicely detailed with a bit of functionality. [image: Angular default homepage]

My question is how does one add the small detailed icons - like the rocket ship at the top, the graduation cap next to "Learn angular" etc? I don't see any image files included in the project for these, are they being sourced from the internet?

How can I use my own images for these small icons in my own project?

Comment: The icon is a SVG [more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rocket is an SVG element, you should find element `<svg>...<svg>` in your index.html.

If you want to use some 3rd party, you can try something like the [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)